# WPF DataGrid huge memory usage

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, datagrid

I have just created a very simple application. I load 10000 objects on startup and bind it to ListView like this:

```
   <ListView Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>    
        </ListView>
```

After that I bind it to DataGrid:

```
  <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" />
```

The difference in case of performance is huge.
ListView: Loading time - less than one second, memory usage 150 MB, after cleaning 137MB
DataGrid: Loading time - a few seconds, memory usage 600MB, after cleaning Objects collection it goes down to 500MB

My biggest concern is that even if collection is empty it doesn't clean everything. Something must be leaking in DataGrid. I have read some about it and the recommendation was not to use DataGridCellTemplate and implement INotifyPropertyChanged in bound items but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: I had this problem happening to me with datagrid. I found that the height of the grid was in fact limitless and therefore all GUI was loaded. To check if this is the problem try to set the Height or MaxHeight property of the control.

Comment: Also, it can take while before the garbage collector gets around to it. Removing items in collection will have marginal effect on Memory Usage.

Comment: How are you measuring memory?

Comment: @Paparazzi just task manager. I tried VS performance tools but it consumes too much memory to even measure it, sick...
Snovva1 yup, I cleaned it and waited a while to check if anything helps but it didnt. Ill try the trick with height, thanks!

Comment: Task manager is not accurate

Comment: Did you place the DataGrid inside a ScrollView? This disables virtualization.